# How can I tell if cuda code is being compiled with relocatable device code?

Tags: cuda, c-preprocessor, nvcc, cufft

In order to use [CUFFT callbacks](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-use-cufft-callbacks-custom-data-processing/), one of the restrictions is that the code must be compiled with relocatable [relocatable device code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-steering-gpu-code-generation).

When this condition is not met, bad things happen; silent failures, wrong answers, etc.

I've got my current build working, but I'd like to make this code more robust against mis-compilation in future projects.

Is there any way to detect this inside the compilation unit? e.g. preprocessor flags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro to use to detect when  `-rdc=true` is specified is:

```
__CUDACC_RDC__
```

published [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#nvcc-identification-macro)

As a simple test case, you could do:

```
$ cat t1.cu
#ifndef __CUDACC_RDC__
#error THIS CODE REQUIRES CUDA RELOCATABLE DEVICE CODE COMPILATION
#endif

int main(){}
$ nvcc -c t1.cu
t1.cu:2:2: error: #error THIS CODE REQUIRES CUDA RELOCATABLE DEVICE CODE COMPILATION
 #error THIS CODE REQUIRES CUDA RELOCATABLE DEVICE CODE COMPILATION
  ^
$ nvcc -rdc=true -c t1.cu
$
```